# Can I get content to overlap scroll bar? CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a situation where the 'bar' div, display some information about the 'foo' element, when the 'foo' element is hovered. But the scroll bar conflict with that, and hide the rest of my div. Can I get it to display the full 'bar' div somehow?

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="foo">
        xxx
        <div class="bar">Info text, info text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.foo {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.bar {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 125px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    right: -30px;
    display: none;
}
.foo:hover > .bar {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Never use `position:relative` with top/bottom left/right to position elements. Just use negative margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `.bar` div to `position:fixed`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfvdujLm/2/)

**CSS**

```
.box {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.foo {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 125px;
    background: orange;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
.foo:hover > .bar {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Solved it, and also this way I don't have to use positioning as @Diodeus mentioned. Thanks! =)